# Javascript + React :- Unable to put the data in table and then render it

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, mobx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from "mobx-react"
import { inject } from "mobx-react"

@observer
export default class TradeTable extends React.Component {


 render() {

  
  var tableData = this.props.store.arr.map((data) => {
   console.log("The data is "+typeof data)         //The data is Object
   console.log(data.date)
   return data
  })

  console.log(tableData)  // Data is available in object form
  return <div className="panel panel-default">
   <div className="panel-body tradeComponent div-background table-responsive">
    <table className="table table-striped tb div-lightbackground">
     <thead className="thead-dark ">
      <tr>
       <th>Commodity</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Side</th>
       <th>Qty (MT)</th>
       <th>Price (MT)</th>
       <th>CounterParty</th>
       <th>Location</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>

       <td>{tableData.date}</td>         //Not working
       <td>{tableData.commodity}</td>
       <td>{tableData.side}</td>
       <td>{tableData.quantity}</td>
       <td>{tableData.price}</td>
       <td>{tableData.counterparty}</td>
       <td>{tableData.location}</td>
      </tr>

     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 }
}
```

I am not able to view the table .I am not getting errors .I am able to view the data whenever i console log it , but i am not able to view the data inside the table.Urgent help needed ..i am trying for hours :(

Comment: Could you please share the `console.log(tableData) `

Comment: Its an array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me tableData is an array. what you are looking for is something like this

```
export default class TradeTable extends React.Component {


    render() {

        return (<div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-body tradeComponent div-background table-responsive">
                <table className="table table-striped tb div-lightbackground">
                    <thead className="thead-dark ">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Commodity</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Side</th>
                            <th>Qty (MT)</th>
                            <th>Price (MT)</th>
                            <th>CounterParty</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         {
       this.props.store.arr.map((tableItem, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>{tableItem.date}</td>
          <td>{tableItem.commodity}</td>
          <td>{tableItem.side}</td>
          <td>{tableItem.quantity}</td>
          <td>{tableItem.price}</td>
          <td>{tableItem.counterparty}</td>
          <td>{tableItem.location}</td>
        </tr>))}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Note that using the `i` (index) as the key is bad practice. so consider using an unique attribute for your key
hope it helps

Comment: So should i remove the table data which is between the render and return  ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. you can do something like that. since your tableData variable was returning the `identity` for each element in the array

Comment: The above code is giving errors...just below the tableItem.locations  ..at the brace of </tr>)}

Comment: Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sudakatux/m0pepv8v/7/ in your case your array comes as props. ive created a constant in the fiddle just as an example.

Comment: Thanks brother @jstuartmilne ..i appreciate your efforts !